# make file issue: error at every line

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I try to build a library of some project. When I run it as ./MakeFile from terminal I get a bunch of errors for every line. Below is the makefile and the errors. What is wrong with it? For other project Makefie works fine, so it is not that the system does not know how to interpret this file. 
Thanks!

```
LIBDIR = ../../lib

IFLAGS = -I../../include -I/usr/local/include

CFLAGS = $(IFLAGS) -O3 -Wunused -m32 #-fPIC

CC = gcc

AR = ar

SRC =   allocfailed.c cleanup.c ECDFwd.c ECDLeadField.c ECDSolve.c ECDSolve2.c \
    GetBasis.c  GetCoeffs.c GetHull.c NLeadField.c NSolveFwd.c NSolveWts.c \
    rnynm.c xbd.c xlubksb.c xludcmp.c

OBJ =   $(SRC:.c=.o)

all:    liblfu.a

liblfu.a: $(OBJ)
    $(AR) cr liblfu.a $(OBJ)
    @mkdir -p $(LIBDIR)
    mv liblfu.a $(LIBDIR)

clean:
    /bin/rm -rf *.o *.il *.a core


./Makefile: line 1: LIBDIR: command not found
./Makefile: line 3: IFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 5: IFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 5: CFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 7: CC: command not found
./Makefile: line 9: AR: command not found
./Makefile: line 11: SRC: command not found
./Makefile: line 15: SRC:.c=.o: command not found
./Makefile: line 15: OBJ: command not found
./Makefile: line 17: all:: command not found
./Makefile: line 19: OBJ: command not found
./Makefile: line 19: liblfu.a:: command not found
./Makefile: line 20: AR: command not found
./Makefile: line 20: OBJ: command not found
./Makefile: line 20: cr: command not found
./Makefile: line 21: LIBDIR: command not found
./Makefile: line 21: @mkdir: command not found
./Makefile: line 22: LIBDIR: command not found
```

Comment: how does the first line of the other, working Makefile look like?

Answer (score 13):

You are running the make file as a script, just type `make`

The make command takes Makefile (or makefile) as a default input.  It is not runnable.

You can make it runnable by adding (assuming make is in /usr/bin)

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
```

as the first line of the file

Comment: Thanks! make worked. But why in other project  ./MakeFile works too?

Comment: Probably not necessary, but `#! /usr/bin/env make -f` might cater for a few odd systems which have `make` in some other place.